# How can I declare just one db variable that will look either to the Entities1.edmx or to Entities2.edmx

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have two schemas in Oracle that have a lot of overlapping tables. But still the data must be kept separate. That is why I have 2 schemas with 80% of the tables exactly the same. I have a windows forms application have two Entity Framework 6 edmx that connect to each schema.

```
PMSEntities pmsdb = new PMSEntities();
GRMSEntities grmsdb = new GRMSEntities();
```

I have a clients entity on both edmx.

To access it, I can do this:

```
if (ispms) 
  pmsdb.clients.whatever;
else 
  grmsdb.clients.whatever;
```

This is just very cumbersome, doing everything twice.

I tried:

```
DbContext db;

if (ispms)
  db = new PMSEntities();
else
  db = new GRMSEntities();

db.clients.whatever;
```

But then db doesn't recognize the Client class.

I tried using just one edmx with client entity on it. Model/Database first. Then just changing and passing the connectionstring if I initialize the edmx. But edmx are built from a specific schema. So although the table name and properties are exactly the same. The edmx just work from the schema the edmx was built from.

The application will only connect to one oracle schema at a time throughout the application. It will either be to GRMS or PMS schema.

How can I declare just one db variable that will look either to the PMSEntities.edmx or the GRMSEntities.edmx.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have two classes with a lot of similar properties and methods: `PmsEntities` and `GRMSEntities`. Although you didn't say so, I think that both classes derive from `DbContext`.

I see two solutions. They have nothing to do with entity framework, just plain simple object oriented programming: either create a class with all DbSets that are in both DbContext. Derive Pms and Grms from this.

Or similar use an interface

```
class BaseDbContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Client> Clients {get; set;}   // both Pms and Grms have Clients
     ...
}

class PmsEntities : BaseDbContext 
{
     public DbSet<OnlyPmsType> OnlyPmsTypes {get; set;}    // only in Pms
     ...
}
class PmsEntities : BaseDbContext  
{
     public DbSet<OnlyGrmsType> OnlyGrmsTypes {get; set;}    // only in Grms
     ...
}
```

The other, somewhat neater solution would be using an interface. Decide what DbSets you want from both Pms and Grms:

```
interface IMyInterface
{
     IDbSet<Client> Clients {get; set;}
     IDbSet<...>  ...

     void SaveChanges();
}

class Pms : DbContext, IMyInterface {...}
class Grms: DbContext, IMyInterface {...}
```

And a factory function:

```
IMyInterface GetDbContext(bool ispms)
{
    return ispms ? new Pms() : new Grms();
}
```

Usage would be as if you have your original DbContext:

```
bool ispms = ...
using (var dbContext = GetDbContext(ispms)
{
     var fetchedClient = dbContext.Clients
         .Where(client => ...)
         .FirstOrDefault();
     if (fetchedClient != null)
     {
          fetchedClient.Name = ...
          dbContext.SaveChanges();
     }
}
```

And of course the compiler ensures sure that you can't access a Pms DbSet that is not a Grms DbSet,